# How to calculate total of two values in PHP?

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
 <?php
    $addition = print $stats->getLastMonthGirl($userid); + print $stats->getLastMonthMale($userid);
    echo "Total:".$addition.""; 
 ?>
```

Not working.

Comment: Print will return 1 if its print the string successfully so it will add 1+1

Comment: @Pramod the semicolons cause the syntax error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are doing something really strange, and for you it is better to learn some programming concepts and syntax of PHP language.

As I understand your idea the correct code will be

```
<?php
$addition = $stats->getLastMonthGirl($userid) + stats->getLastMonthMale($userid);
echo "Total:".$addition.""; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$addition = $stats->getLastMonthGirl($userid) + $stats->getLastMonthMale($userid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `print` statements:

```
$addition = $stats->getLastMonthGirl($userid) + $stats->getLastMonthMale($userid); 

echo "Total:".$addition."";
```

In PHP a function call returns a value which doesn't need to be printed to be used.

Also you cannot fit semicolon separated statements together without removing the semicolons.